# "Vote to close" behaviour not consistent between review and question pages?

Tags: bug

So, I'm reviewing this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746312/libgdx-making-a-smooth-scrolling-transition-like-the-game-fall-down

This is a repeat question, the original being here: [libGDX - How do I make a Tiled Map scroll like the game Fall Down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665871/libgdx-how-do-i-make-a-tiled-map-scroll-like-the-game-fall-down)

The original question does not have an accepted answer. When I saw it in the "close votes" review page, I tried to close it as a duplicate, and supplied the original URL. I'm told I can't do that, because there's no accepted answer. If I got to the question page itself and hit the "close" link, the same set of options pop up, but I can supply the original unanswered question as a duplicate (and it seems like several other people have done so).

Does this mean that the "close" vote link under the question and the "close votes" page under the review section are actually totally different things, despite their similarity, or does it mean that there's a bug in one or the other?

edit:

I've just noticed that I can vote to close from a question's page even after I've used up all of my 40 close votes that the review section allows me. That should be a slightly easier to replicate issue.

Comment: In response to your edit, your mixing up the maximum number of reviews you can do and the number of close votes.  You can **review** 40 posts from the close vote review queue.  It doesn't matter whether you vote to close to vote to leave open, you can only do 40.  But you get 50 close votes per day, so whatever you have left after reviewing your 40 posts can be used to close questions directly from the question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 why is there a difference between the two, though? Especially only a 10-vote different, seems like a silly distinction.

Comment: I don't know why the specific numbers were picked, but there reason for the difference is they aren't the same actions in reality.  It think the right answer is too long for a comment (if you are really curious you can ask a question).  But in short, the difference is there because voting to close specific posts is not the same a reviewing questions, and often when you are done reviewing, you still may need a few votes left to vote to close questions you come across through normal means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you weren't allowed to close a duplicate post from the review queue, but where able to close it from the question page, then it would appear to be a bug.  There isn't any special rules that prevent closure from the review queue, but allow it from the main page.

Normally, when you vote to close a question as a duplicate you are not permitted to close a question that does not have an accepted answer, an upvoted answer, or multiple answers.  However, questions where the author is the same is the exception to the rule.<sup>1</sup>

So if the review queue is preventing you from doing that, then there may be a problem.  You should double check that the duplicate target URL you were using was correct and you didn't accidentally mistype it or copy the wrong one.

<sub>The reason for the exception is to prevent users from reasking the same question over and over.  When you ask a question that does not get an answer, it is **not** appropriate to reask the same question over and over again.  It is not really necessary to reask a question as there are tools to get attention for a post already that don't involve reasking the same thing over and over again.</sub>